# Gettings started with Ruby on Rails 2.0 for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby

So like many people, I'm excited about Ruby on Rails. Being a Windows user, I downloaded InstantRails, got it going, and followed along with the screencast on how to make a blog with RoR 2.0 in fifteen minutes. I used Notepad++ as my text editor, because that's what I've traditionally used for writing the PHP-based websites I've done in the past. I was a little envious of Mac users and how they get the really attractive-looking TextMate, but I managed to follow through the entire screencast and get everything working smoothly.

However, I was lost most of the time.

I know plenty of programming and scripting languages over the years - C++, JavaScript, PHP, HTML, and Lua just to name a few. I don't know Ruby, but I understand a lot of how it works, as far as the syntax is concerned, but I don't understand a lot of the logic behind why certain files do certain things, and that sort of thing.

Also, I tried Aptana with RadRails, but found it difficult to set up. Is there any concrete tutorial for getting it set up and working fully with Ruby on Rails 2.0?

Should I maybe just wait for more RoR 2.0 tutorials to come out before attempting to learn RoR? Or should I just plow on through and experiment until I figure it out?

Comment: If you can be more specific on what logic you're curious about and what files, I'm sure we could gladly answer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really serious about learning Rails, my advice is to **get a good book and read it** (I know.. programmers don't read books, but you should!). A "*good book on Rails*" usually contain a chapter on Ruby, but there are plenty of resources on the web to get you going.

According to [Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html):

> It is highly recommended that you
>   **familiarize yourself with Ruby before diving into Rails**. You will
>   find it much easier to follow what's
>   going on with a Rails application if
>   you understand basic Ruby syntax.
>   Rails isn't going to magically
>   revolutionize the way you write web
>   applications if you have no experience
>   with the language it uses.

I'm personally using [Simply Rails 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/rails2/), which uses (surprise, surprise) Rails 2. It walks you through the development of a Digg clone.

If you still don't wanna use a book, you should check out [Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and the [Ruby on Rails Wiki](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails). AFAIK, They are being regularly updated to keep up with new releases of Rails.

Comment: Programmers don't read books? I guess I missed that lesson early on in life :)

I'll look into the Rails 2.0 BETA book that someone else posted, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Also you may want to look into NetBeans, it has great support for ruby and rails. They also provide several focused tutorials and even viedos.

http://www.netbeans.org/kb/trails/ruby.html

Another excelent source of focused tutorials is http://railscasts.com/ by Ryan Bates.

On the ruby side, I strongly recommend The Ruby Way, and if you are into screencasts, the Pragmatic Programmers have some cheap and excelent ones on ruby object model and metaprogramming by Dave Thomas.

Answer (score 2):

Pragmatic Programmer's [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails) is an excellent book to get started with.

There is a [RoR 2.0 BETA book](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) available as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails Way is also a good book. I use it everyday as a reference book.

Answer (score 1):

You could always check out the awesome Peepcode screencast series:

[Rails 2 from scratch part I](https://peepcode.com/products/rails-from-scratch-part-i)

[Rails 2 from scratch part II](https://peepcode.com/products/rails-from-scratch-part-ii)

You'll be off and running in no time after watching those.  I would also recommend [Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com), a (free) weekly screencast on Rails, usually focusing on a single feature or implementing a concept in a wonderfully produced manner.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, though, it looks like many of these books and such are now at least partially outdated with the advent of Rails 2.0. Is this true?

Comment: Check out the beta book I linked too in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

InstantRails has not been updated for a while, check out [Rubystack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack), which is a similar project but we also include a bunch of other tools: Apache, MySQL,Imagemagick, etc.